# Test Suite for Smart Home don't execute action

Tags: google-smart-home

I am trying to execute Test Suite to certify, but I receive an error when executing the action. I can't find anything in the Google Cloud log. Everything works fine using Google Assistant on my phone and Nest.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kL8Tu.png)

Answer (score 0):

A 503 error code means that the requested service is temporarily unavailable at the moment. You can wait for some time before trying again & make sure that your Smart Home Actions are linked with an account & testing is enabled for your actions. For instructions on how to set up your account for testing, check this [link](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/testing#setup).

If the issue still persists, open up a ticket on our [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148).